# jQuery UI datepicker reinstantiation blues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having some trouble with jQuery UI's datepicker script and am hoping someone here may be able to help.

I need to be able to dynamically create the elements that require the datepicker plugin, then destroy them, then re-create them.  (I make heavy use of jTemplates for this.)

Unfortunately, datepicker only appears to work the first time an element is created, even when it is reinstantiated.

For example, let's say I have inserted the following html into the DOM dynamically using jTemplates:

```
<div id="dateWrapper">
   <input type="text" id="dateChooser" />
</div>
```

I then instantiate the datepicker:

```
$("#dateChooser").datepicker();
```

This works like a charm.

However, if I then remove the dateWrapper element from the DOM...

```
$("#dateWrapper").remove();
```

...and then re-insert it a second time using jTemplates, exactly the same as before, a second call to instantiate datepicker...

```
$("#dateChooser").datepicker();
```

...no longer works.

I have tried calling datepicker's destroy method before removing #dateWrapper from the DOM, and I have even manually tried removing the #ui-datepicker-div that gets injected into the bottom of the DOM when datepicker is first instantiated.  However neither of these has fixed the problem.

Does anyone have any other ideas?  I would hate to have to ditch datepicker, as it is a nice little calendar, and I am already making heavy use of jQuery UI.  However this may be a dealbreaker for me if I can't find a workaround.

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Travis

Comment: Does it work if you create an element with a different ID? for example `dateWrapper-2`. If so it shouldn't be so hard to use some UUID generator for every new element.

Comment: After more experimenting it looks as though I was mistaken about the cause of the problem...  Apparently when datepicker injects its html it assigns the wrapper a z-index of 10000.  I also use z-index: 10000 to describe my highest layers (just a habit) - and it was conflicting.  Soon as I changed all of my custom highest layers to z-index 9999 datepicker worked fine.  So, moral of the story:  If you are using datepicker, avoid z-index: 10000 for other elements on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to use the [`datepicker('destroy')` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-destroy) for removing the `datepicker`, like this:

```
var date = $('#date');

date.datepicker();

$('#create').click(function(){
    date.datepicker();

    return false;
});

$('#destroy').click(function(){
    date.datepicker("destroy");

    return false;
});
```

**See: http://jsfiddle.net/ESX3P/**